# Why is factoring in NP, but not in P?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, np

Factoring: Gven an integer N, find integers 1 < a, b < N such that N = ab if they exist, otherwise say N is prime.

I know that primality testing is in P, but why not factoring?

Here is my algorithm:

```
For each a = 1 ... sqrt(N)
    if(N % a == 0)
        b = N/a
        add (a,b) to the result
    Endif
EndFor
```

This runs in O(sqrt(N)).

Comment: The size of the input is the number of bits required to represent it, not the value of the input.

Comment: [obligatory Wikipedia reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Difficulty_and_complexity)

Comment: If you're *really* asking why cryptology works and stuff like RSA is so hard to break, you're missing the fact that it's a **modulo** factorization.

Comment: The polynomial time primality testing algorithm is nothing like this algorithm, btw.

Comment: @phoeagon Wouldn't it be amazing if there were a 6 liner posted on SO that solved P vs NP?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The input size of a single numeric value, is measured by the length of its binary representation. To be precise, the size of an input numeric value `n` is proportional to `log_2(n)`. Therefore your algorithm runs in expotential time.

For instance, suppose we are factoring a number `N` with your algorithm. If `N` is prime, you have to test at least `sqrt(N)` factors. (Or alternatively you can compute a prime number table for this but it is still not linear).

Anyway, you test for `sqrt(N)` times. But the size of the problem is defined as `S=log2(N)`. So we have `N=2^S`. Therefore it's a `sqrt(2^S)=2^(S/2)` which is expotential.

Comment: I am sorry, I still don' understand why it's exponential time. So, for input size N, it's actually 2^N, you mean?

Comment: @Nayana The algorithm runs in O(sqrt(2^n)) = about O(1.414^n), where n is the number of bits required to store the input number N (i.e. n = log2(N)).

Comment: @nayana updated my answer. sorry for taking so loooong though.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Saying that a linear time algorithm is also exponential is simply a contradiction. I don't know why you think that is true.

Comment: @phoeagon I think I understand what you mean. Thank your very much for clarification.

Comment: @interjay Ok got it! The input size is very small and Hence the seemingly normal time also becomes exponential compared to the size of the problem :)

Comment: @phoeagon I think what Abhishek Bansal said previously kinda make sense too. Let's say we pass an array and try to find a specific number in the array. The running of a problem is obviously O(N), but the size of the problem is again S=log2(N), because it's measured by the length of its binary representation? This interpretation makes every polynomial time algorithm exponential...

Comment: @Nayana I understand. The problem is, this measure of input size is artificial and somehow arbitrary. You have to obey it to make yourself understood.

Comment: @Nayana or try to think it this way. A problem with a single numeric value as input is likely a mathematical problem and therefore it is expected to manipulate gigantic figures. Besides, if we take into account the `O(logV)` part of an array of values smaller than `V`, then we have to do a substitution. The inverse function of `O(NlogN)` is not trivial and likely cause confusion. Furthermore, between `N` & `NlogN` really is a small difference, but among `1`, `logN` and `N` it is not.